# Periodically update local data with server in Flutter

Tags: http, flutter, dart

I'm using Flutter in my app and I'd like to synchronise my local data with the server's data.
The reason is because the data is displayed on a few devices at the same time and I'd like to always show the updated data on those devices. (It's not a problem if there is delay of a few seconds. I don't need it to be instantly synchronised)

I know that Firebase is the perfect candidate for this purpose. But I don't have any control on the backend. I have a REST API and I have to find a way to work with it. (Note that I use the [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http) package to request the API)

I believe that a good option would be to subscribe the devices to push notifications. And every time that the data are updated on the server, a push notification is sent to them so they know that they have to request the API. However, as I sad, I don't have any control on the backend.

So, the only thing I can think about is a timer that fetches the data periodically (i.e. every 10 seconds).

Can you tell me if this is a good option? If yes, how you would achieve it. If no, what better option do I have?

(Note that I'm using the Provider pattern in order to update the UI (but that's not really important for you to know).

Thank you very much in advance :)

Comment: A more reliable way would be using Sockets (google for "flutter socket.io"). Every time there's an event in the stream - all the subscribed devices receive updates. This way you don't have to loop-query the api for changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the body of the screen that you want to update periodically inside streambuilder class . In the stream parameter you can provide the firestore instance from which you are fetching data ,if there is any change in data like deletion or creation it will be reflected in your ui .